# Request to change color of badge notification icon

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, design

[image]

The color of the badge notification icon almost merges into the background. Also, Sometimes when you have both `Answers-Comments` notification icon and badge notification icons, your hardly able to notice the badge one. The `Answers-Comments` icon stands out as it is red in color but the badge icon is somehow not significantly highlighted.

Can we request changing the current color to something more noticeable and highlighted?

Comment: These notifications really aren't important so personally I consider this color a good move.

Answer (score 12):

While I agree they're not as important, the little bubble up in the corner is already hard enough to notice without it having to blend into the background. The color is much more noticeable on the beta theme where it stands out. It needs to be customized more on these sites where it's *not* noticeable.

**Noticeability on sites where it blends into the background:**

[image: Meta Stack Overflow]

[image: Pro Webmasters]

[image: AskUbuntu]

**Compared to noticeability on sites where it contrasts the background:**

[image: Gaming]

[image: Beta Theme]

---

As you can see, some sites have a very high contrast to the sky blue, which makes it stick out just as much as the red. Other sites, such as Stack Overflow and Pro Webmasters, do not, which can make it much harder to tell you even have a notification. Therefore, I conclude that the "this notification isn't as important" argument is invalid. It's clearly not as "hidden" on other sites. The sites where it's hard to see just need a slightly altered, more noticeable color, or a color that better contrasts throughout all the sites.